# Thunderbird - show starred messages above thread pane?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I'd like to show starred emails at the top of the thread pane, without having to click a filter or perform a search (even a saved one) - much like Gmail with priority/starred inbox.

I've searched the addons but I can't find anything - does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: In the columns row at the top ---> |*|@| Subject| | From | |Date|  you can click on the star column and have it sort by star. still messes up the date sort though right?

Comment: Yep, and it also only shows for that folder (e.g. inbox). I sort my emails by client, so I'd like a way of displaying them permanently from all folders so I know what emails need attention.